# Multiple filter for 2sxc module

Tags: 2sxc

Im looking how to make a search app for 2sxc but with multiple exclusive filter.

If you add more filters results have to be reduced, and if you dont have any filter I need to show all items.

Im looking something similar to https://2sxc.org/en/Apps module

Any Idea on how to do it ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is fairly easy to do - there are many versions. One option is to use the Fallback stream (requires a newer 2sxc version) or the fallbackdatasource. I believe you'll find a good example in the blog app - see https://2sxc.org/en/apps/app/dnn-blog-app-for-dnn-dotnetnuke

Comment: Thanks, Streamfallback was the solution

Comment: @Ufoloko great. Best mark this as answered for future users